# Can PostSharp add its Nuget packages from an Artifactory source that is secured?

Tags: postsharp

I'm trying to use the **Add PostSharp to project** "wizard" to set it up on an existing project. Our company allows only using an internal Artifactory instance as Nuget source, and that is secured (requires authentication). It works fine for normal Nuget stuff, both fro command line and in VS.

The PostSharp wizard fails when it tries to add the Nuget packages to my project, because it's getting 401 (Unauthorized) responses from Artifactory.

Is there a way to force the wizard to authenticate, or to use standard nuget which is already set up with Artifactory as a source (with credentials)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In normal case PostSharp wizard uses standard nuget, if it doesn't then it is most likely a bug (you can report it at http://support.sharpcrafters.com/).

Anyway PostSharp is a normal nuget package and you can install it directly using Nuget Package Manager without bothering with **Add PostSharp to project** wizard.